# Can music ever be considered useful (or not forbidden) in the light of Islam?

Tags: music

Music has always been talked about as harmful is Islam, be it a description in a religious book or a quote from a scholar. I've always read (and been told) that music (being a distraction) is something that takes one away from God.

However, I've always had a different experience with music. It lets me focus better, self-reflect, think about the past, envision the future, feel closer to (or appreciate) nature/life, realize that this life in this world is temporary, and that's just a small list of effects. I've tried to stay away from music many times during my life but have failed to do so to this day.

By any remote chance, (and I know this could be very subjective) could there be any particular genre of music that could be permissible (or at least not forbidden), given that most mentions of harmful music that I've come across talks about lyrics as the evil while my interest lies around music with minimal to no vocals at all?

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: @UmH Yes. There's a lot of explanation over there. Thanks!

Comment: Salaam, the link above offers you a variety of views. After making your mind on it, you may want to try the works by Sami Yusuf, a pious world-renowned Muslim singer. There's a genuine love and purity in his spiritual works that are uplifting.

Comment: I found a pretty old video from 2015 featuring Mufti Ismail Menk on YouTube and he explained most of what I asked within 2.5 minutes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDrPbgE9h58

Answer (score 0):

> Music has always been talked about as harmful is Islam.

Music itself is not haram in Islam; it is hedonism that is; given the association of music with hedonism, this is why music has been seen as haram; nevertheless, the real point is against hedonism:

> And of mankind there is he who purchases idle talks to mislead men from the Path of Allah and is without knowledge, and mocks the Path of Allah. For such there will be a humiliating torments.
>
> Qu'ran 31:6

Idle talk here can be lies, music, dance and so on.

Comment: There is a considerable scholars who said music is haram

Comment: @AmerYR: I've read scholarly opinion who do regard it a such for reasons I've explained above.

Comment: you connect it with " hedonism " ? the real point is against hedonism!

Comment: @AmerYR: I don't see the relevance of your comment.